# Почему после того как я наследовал шаблон появляется просто чистая страница?

Tags: django

Подскажите, где я ошибся пожалуйста.

**base.html**

```
{% block header %}
<header class="header">
    <div class="logo" style="color: #fff">
      <img src="/media/images/logo/Безымянный-2.svg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="menubox" onclick="openFunction()">&#9776;</div>
    <div id="menu" class="sidemenu">
      <a href="#main-screen__content">Главная</a>
      <a href="#gallery">О нас</a>
      <a href="#advantages">Услуги</a>
      <a href="#rooms">Номера</a>
      <a href="/reviews">Отзывы</a>
      <a href="#address">Карта</a>
      <a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="closeFunction()">&times;</a>
    </div>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#main-screen__content">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#gallery">О нас</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#advantages">Услуги</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#rooms">Номера</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="/reviews">Отзывы</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#address">Карта</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="reservation">
      <button class="button-request">Забронировать</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  {% endblock %}
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %} {% load recaptcha3 %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alice&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/sliderHome.css' %}" />

  {% recaptcha_init %} {% recaptcha_ready action_name='homepage' %}

  <title>GRIZLY</title>
</head>

<body>
  {% include './messages.html' %}

  {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
  <section class="section_100vh main-screen">
    <div class="container">

      {% block header %}
      {% endblock %}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не правильно сделан каркас шаблонов, вы пытаетесь наследоваться от базового шаблона, но в нем, к примеру, нет {% block content %}, но есть блог {% block header %}, а в {% block header %} в шаблоне home.html вы ничего не пишете, да даже если бы и писали, вы затерли бы информацию из базового шаблона. Вам надо создать правильный каркас страницы и разместить базовую информацию вне блоков, а нужные блоки пустыми, например - {% block header %} {% block title %} {% block content %}. Наследуясь от базового шаблона вы переопределяете только то, что находится в заранее определенных блоках, внутри их границ.

base.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  {% block content%} {% endblock content%}
</body>

</html>
```

home.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  Привет {{request.user}}!тут будет контент :)<br>
  <a href="{% url 'admin:login'%}">Администрирование</a><br>

{% endblock %}
```